# Class error whilst reconstructing a serialized object

Tags: java, deserialization

I have two programs, HunterClient and HunterServer

Both Programs have a main class and a Message class. The message class is an exact copy other than one is within the HunterClient project and one is in the HunterServer project. (both have a project deceleration within the class)

This is how I send the first object through the Client

```
String str = scanner.next();
//Send down Stream
out.writeObject(new Message(str));
out.flush();
```

This is how I receive the object at the other end

```
try {
 Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("err... " + ex);
        }
```

However running this and trying to send a message from the client to the server I get the following error message.

err... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hunterclient.Message

That message is received on HunterMessenger not HunterClient. Both programs are built as netbeans projects... The way im understanding this error is that the program is looking for the hunterclient class in the huntermessenger program... how can I make it use its native messenger class?

These are my two message classes

The Server

```
package huntermessenger;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable{

private String message;

public Message(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}
}
```

The Client

```
package hunterclient;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable{

private String message;

public Message(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the HunterClient class Serializable?

Comment: Yeah, both are seaializable, exact copies of each other apart from the project decleration

Comment: The both Message class in client and server is considered different according to JVM.The client class looks for server Message Class that is why you are getting class not found exception.

Comment: Ok... Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Just have the Message class as jar file in your Client class.and import the Message class in Client side.